# Sum all rows returned in query and use it in each row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query (Oracle) that shows the sales of each customer by years:

```
SELECT cmp.company_key
    , sum(CASE WHEN sd.date between TO_DATE('01-Jan-2010', 'dd-mm-yyyy') and TO_DATE('11-Jun-2010', 'dd-mm-yyyy') THEN sd.qty_ship * sd.unit_price END) AS year1sales
    , sum(CASE WHEN sd.date between TO_DATE('01-Jan-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') and TO_DATE('11-Jun-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') THEN sd.qty_ship * sd.unit_price END) AS year2sales
FROM sales_detail sd
INNER JOIN sales_header sh on sd.sales_header_key = sh.sales_header_key
INNER JOIN companies cmp on sh.company_key = cmp.company_key
GROUP BY cmp.company_key
```

The query produces this:

```
company_key | year1sales | year2sales
------------|------------|------------
       8687 |   21355.76 |   54326.45
         25 |    9375.41 |      12401
         34 |    6440.03 |   50349.27
        247 |   47355.93 |   77432.67
         83 |   15757.35 |   39999.12
```

But I also need it to return a value ("TBI") showing what percentage that company's sales are compared to the sum of all the other sales numbers.

So, for company #8687 it would be `21355.76 / sigma(year1 sales)` which is `21355.76/100,284.48 = 21.3%`.

So the result would be:

```
company_key | year1sales | year1 TBI | year2sales | year1 TBI
------------|------------|-----------|------------|----------
       8687 |   21355.76 |     21.30 |   54326.45 |     23.17
         25 |    9375.41 |      9.35 |      12401 |      5.29
         34 |    6440.03 |      6.42 |   50349.27 |     21.47
        247 |   47355.93 |     47.22 |   77432.67 |     33.02
         83 |   15757.35 |     15.71 |   39999.12 |     17.06
```

And obviously the TBI columns would sum up to 100%.

How would you write this query? Also, what is the time complexity for a problem like this? I think it's O(n^2) best case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `SUM OVER` to get the totals:

```
select
  company_key,
  year1sales,
  year1sales / sum(year1sales) over() as year1tbi,
  year2sales,
  year2sales / sum(year2sales) over() as year2tbi
from
(
  SELECT cmp.company_key
      , sum(CASE WHEN sd.date between date '2010-01-01' and date '2010-06-11' THEN sd.qty_ship * sd.unit_price END) AS year1sales
      , sum(CASE WHEN sd.date between date '2011-01-01' and date '2011-06-11' THEN sd.qty_ship * sd.unit_price END) AS year2sales
  FROM sales_detail sd
  INNER JOIN sales_header sh on sd.sales_header_key = sh.sales_header_key
  INNER JOIN companies cmp on sh.company_key = cmp.company_key
  GROUP BY cmp.company_key
)
order by company_key;
```

As to the complexity: I cannot answer this. The DBMS has to run through the result, build the totals and calculate the percentages per row then.

Comment: On complexity: right. And the DBMS' strategy seems like it could take a bad approach to this if not careful (i.e., calculating the total for each row and then updating each row for each row ...)

Comment: [`RATIO_TO_REPORT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions124.htm) should simplify it a bit.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I think your answer is more correct so if you leave it as an answer I'll mark it

Comment: @ryvantage No need for. Feel free to rewrite your query to RATIO_TO_REPORT as exercise :)

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda: Thanks for mentioning the `RATIO_TO_REPORT` function. I didn't know of it. Yes that simplifies the expression slightly, but more importantly it deals with division by zero, which I haven't even considered in my expressions. So my expression would have had to be `year1sales / nullif(sum(year1sales) over (), 0)` which becomes a mere `ratio_to_report(year1sales) over ()`.